# can't able to play Audio in ios 9

Tags: objective-c, audio, xcode8, ios9

Currently I am facing a problem which is, I am not able to play audio url into iPad. I go throw many documents. Any one please help me out.
here is my current code under Action. What's wrong into my current code...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://megdadhashem.wapego.ru/files/56727/tubidy_mp3_e2afc5.mp3"];

// create a session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

// create player
audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
audioplayer.delegate = self;
[audioplayer prepareToPlay];
[audioplayer play];
```

Comment: your code is correct, check that device once.

Answer (score 0):

Set this category:

```
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```